# Angular HTTP Request, Tomcat deletes my custom header?

Tags: angular, tomcat, httprequest

I'm running a jersey rest service which handles my http requests and a tomcat server(v. 8.5.3) which hosts my angular app.
Inside my angular app im doing the following http request :

```
getCustomerData(customer): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'apiKey': 'test1234'});
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/test/data/'+customer,options).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

When running my angular app with the built in dev webserver the http request my request has the added property "apiKey" inside the header.
[angular dev webserver http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk4Jg.png)
After building my angular app with `ng build --prod` and hosting the built app with a tomcat server the http request doesn't include the property "apiKey" in my request header.
[tomcat http request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql2lx.png)
Its simple missing but its exact the same code as I used before? Why does my custom header property gets 'removed' or blocked?
I've also added following XML options inside the tomcat web.xml (conf/web.xml)

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,apiKey,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

EDIT based on the comment, using an interceptor now:

Im using an interceptor now :
Using `import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';` for my http request
Changed my Get request to :

```
getCustomerData(customer): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+'/test/data/'+customer).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

added an interceptor :

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest,HttpHandler,HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class CustomhttpinterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):   Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log("interceptor called");
    var header = req.headers;
    header = header.append('apiKey','test1234');
    var newHeader = req.clone({headers:header});
    return next.handle(newHeader);
 }
}
```

And added everything to my app.module.ts (HttpClientModule import only appears once in the entire project, only in app.module.ts)

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {CustomhttpinterceptorService} from './services/customhttpinterceptor.service';
```

added HttpClientModule to imports and the following object to providers :

```
{provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:CustomhttpinterceptorService,multi:true}
```

When using Angular Dev-server the custom property(apiKey) is appended to the header and I see the console.log I made in my interceptor ("interceptor called").
When hosting the built Angular App with my tomcat the http request still doesnt work. The property is still not there + I get the following error message :

```
ERROR TypeError: w.throw is not a function
    at ya.handleError [as selector] (main-es2015.f9cd60892ac728ec6952.js:formatted:20752)
```

Seems like the app throws the error before calling the interceptor since the console.log won't get called. Why would it work on the dev server but not on the tomcat server?

Comment: Reg the errors - confirm if you have imported the right operators from rxjs

Comment: @NicholasK
I cannot find the error, develop tools says the following :
`handleError(e) {
  var t = JSON.parse(e.text());
  return w.throw(t.error)
}` , (he simply cannot do w.throw,but why?) my handle error method :
`handleError(err) {
  return throwError(err);
}`
my only rxjs imports are `import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';` and `import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';`

Comment: Is this a compile time error?

Comment: Yes it seems like a compile time error.

Comment: Could you share that file in the question?